# What does this lyric in "I Don't Know" by MiSTah Kye mean?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

At around 2:09 in the song *"I Don't Know"* by *MiSTah Kye*, there is this lyric:

> She murder like Bobby

Which "Bobby" is this referencing?

In his songs, *MiSTah Kye* usually references British pop culture (such as *One Direction*), so I wonder if this could be regarding Bobby Beale in *EastEnders*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he means "Bobby shmurder" the US rapper